# Getting out of a function in Python

Tags: python, exception, function

I want to get out of a function when an exception occurs or so.
I want to use other method than 'return'

Answer (score 19):

If you catch an exception and then want to rethrow it, [this pattern](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200711/rethrowing_exceptions_in_python.html) is pretty simple:

```
try:
    do_something_dangerous()
except:
    do_something_to_apologize()
    raise
```

Of course if you want to *raise* the exception in the first place, that's easy, too:

```
def do_something_dangerous(self):
    raise Exception("Boo!")
```

If that's not what you wanted, please provide more information!

Answer (score 4):

Can't think of another way to "get out" of a function other than a) return, b) throw an exception, or c) terminate execution of the program.

Comment: Class c) is a subclass of b): raise SystemExit

Comment: I was referring more to terminating the process (manually from outside the program?). Good point though.

Answer (score 4):

The exception itself will terminate the function:

```
def f():
    a = 1 / 0  # will raise an exception
    return a

try:
    f()
except:
    print 'no longer in f()'
```

Comment: Right, one would certainly imagine so. Which leads me to ask what the original question is /really/ asking for...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to "stop" execution inside of that method. There's a few things you can do.

1. **Don't catch the exception.** This will return control to the method that called it in the first place. You can then do whatever you want with it.
2. **sys.exit(0)** This one actually exits the entire program.
3. **return** I know you said you don't want return, but hear me out. Return is useful, because based on the value you return, it would be a good way to let your users know what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, an exception will get you out of the method.  You shouldn't be ashamed or embarassed by exceptions; an exception indicates an **error**, but that's not necessarily the same as a **bug**.

For example, say I'm writing a factorial function.  Factorial isn't defined for negative numbers, so I might do this:

```
def factorial(n):
  if n < 0:
    raise ValueError
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  return n*factorial(n-1)
```

I would then look for the exception:

```
n = raw_input('Enter a number.')
try:
  print factorial(n)
except ValueError:
  print 'You entered a negative number.'
```

I can make the exception more informative than a ValueError by defining my own:

```
class NegativeInputError(Exception):
  pass

# in the function:
if n < 0:
  raise NegativeInputError
```

HTH!